# has_many through with an extra column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I'm working on an problem I can't solve.

I have the following:

Groups table:

```
create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Groupships table:

```
create_table "groupships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "group_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.boolean  "owner"
  t.text     "permission"
end
```

group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :groupships
   has_many :groups, through: :groupships
end
```

groupship.rb:

```
class Groupship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :group
end
```

I want to see if a user is the owner of a group and what permissions the user has, through groupship.
Is that possible, or do I have to make a group_perssions table?

I tried this in a view:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
   <div class="well well-small">
      <h3><%= group.name %></h3>
      Owner: <%= group.groupships.owner %> //True or false readout for development.
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that a group has many users through groupships? And do you mean to say that a group has many groups? Your group model seems odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the example you gave of your Groupship class may be slightly wrong. Shouldn't it be..

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groupships
  has_many :users, through: :groupships
end
```

A group can have many users and a user can have many groups right?

As for the view example you gave, you can't simply call `group.groupships.owner` because `group.groupships` is a collection, and the owner boolean is a property of a single groupship. You could do something like this instead:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <div class="well well-small">
    <h3><%= group.name %></h3>
    Owners:
    <%= group.groupships.each do |groupship| %>
      <%= groupship.user.name %>:
      <%= groupship.owner? %>
    <% end -%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey Peter! Thank you for your help, it works, with a little modification:

    <%= groupship.user.owner? %> should be <%= groupship.owner? %>